# JavaScript Regex match only if character occurs only ones followed by alphanumeric character

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I want a JavaScript Regex which matches the character `&` only if it occurs exactly one time followed by a alphanumeric character.

Examples:

- `&De&&let&&&e A&ll` → Should only match `&D` and `&l`
- `Hum&&an&s`  → should only match `&s`

This is what I have come up with but it is not quite right:

```
(?:[^\&]|^)\&([a-zA-Z0-9])
```

```js
var strings = `&De&&let&&&e A&ll
 Hum&&an&s`

console.log(
  strings.match(/(?:[^\&]|^)\&([a-zA-Z0-9])/g)
)
```

Comment: What is the final goal? [Replace the matches with something else?](https://jsfiddle.net/d2q8c2ep/) Your regexps seem quite fine, you may turn the `([a-zA-Z0-9])` into a `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])` lookahead though.

Comment: I made you a snippet.  Please update with what expected output should be exactly

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my regex matches `A&l` and `n&s` but I want to match only `&s` and `&l`

Yes, the goal is to replace the matches.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/d2q8c2ep/1/

Comment: Your code is fine. You only have to make first group to a capturing group then include them while invoking replace method.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok I see so the dollar sign is used to get the first group ?

Comment: You can post your answers and I will accept them.

Comment: Yes, `$1` is the replacement backreference (or, placeholder) for the value stored in Group 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the first group into a [*capturing group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) so that you could restore the value inside the replaced string with a `$1` placeholder (also called [*replacement backreference*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html)). In the similar way, you may restore the alphanumeric char captured into another group.

Here is an example of replacing `&` with `#` in the contexts you defined:

```js
var strs = ['&De&&let&&&e A&ll', 'Hum&&an&s'];
var rx = /(^|[^&])&([A-Z0-9])/gi;
for (var s of strs) {
 console.log(s.replace(rx, "$1#$2"));
}
```